# Direct image of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of projective varieties and $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle on $X$. How can I compute explicitly $f_*\mathcal{E}$ in various situations?

For example, let $Y=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $X$ be a conic. What is $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$?

Answer (score 10):

This is a great question! Hopefully someone more knowledgable than I can give a fulfilling answer. I can only offer a few parlor tricks

---

For example, if you have a finite flat morphism $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1_k$, where $X/k$ is a smooth curve, then $f_\ast\mathcal{E}$ will be a vector bundle. Then, by Grothendieck's theorem you know that

$$f_\ast\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{O}(n_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathcal{O}(n_m)$$

You can then often times deduce what the $n_i$ are from cohomology computations. Namely, since $f$ is affine, you know that

$$H^i\left(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(n_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathcal{O}(n_m)\right)=H^i\left(X,\mathcal{E}\right)$$

the right hand side which you probably know. This will give you a set of equations on the $n_i$ which will usually determine them uniquely (hopefully!).

More generally, if you know what your map $X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ is given by $\mathscr{L}$ then you have the extra data

$$H^i(\mathbb{P}^1,f_\ast\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{O}(n))=H^i(X,\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathscr{L}^{\otimes n})$$

> ***Example:*** Suppose that $f:E\to\mathbb{P}^1$ is a degree two, non-constant, where $E$ is genus $1$. Then, by degree considerations you know that $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_E$ is $\mathcal{O}(n_1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(n_2)$. But, using the observation above, you have that
>
> $$H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(n_1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(n_2))=H^0(E,\mathcal{O}_E)=1$$
>
> and so clearly we must have, without loss of generality, that $n_1=0$, and $n_2<0$. But, we also have the equation
>
> $$1=H^1(E,\mathcal{O}_E)=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1_k,\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(n_2))=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(n_2))$$
>
> Looking at the list of values for the cohomology of line bundles, you see that this forces $n_2=-2$. So, $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_E=\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(-2)$.

---

In a different vein, if you're map $f:X\to Y$ is finite, then you could leverage the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(X/Y)$ on $f_\ast\mathcal{E}$ and compute its decomposition into irreducibles (assuming nice enough situations).

> ***Example:*** Let's analyze the same example as above, but under this light. Let's assume, for obvious reasons, that $\mathrm{char}(k)\ne 2$. We have an action of $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ on $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_E$ gives us a decomposition into the $\pm 1$-eigenspaces. Thus, we have a decomposition
>
> $$f_\ast\mathcal{O}_E=\mathcal{O}_+\oplus\mathcal{O}_-$$
>
> That said, it's clear that $\mathcal{O}_+=\mathcal{O}$ (why)? That said, since $\mathcal{O}_E=\Omega^1_E$ we have the trace map
> $$\mathrm{tr}:f_\ast\Omega^1_E=f_\ast\mathcal{O}_E\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^1}=\mathcal{O}(-2)$$
> which is surjective. I think a bit of thought will show that $\ker\mathrm{tr}=\mathcal{O}$, and thus we have an extension
> $$0\to \mathcal{O}\to f_\ast\mathcal{O}_E\to\mathcal{O}(-2)$$
> but of course this splits since
> $$\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}(-2),\mathcal{O})=\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O}(2))=0$$

Comment: +1 Dear Alex, could you please explain where your formula comes from? (I can't  make sense of it the way it is written)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Hey Georges! Which formula are you referencing?

Comment: This formula: $f_\ast(\mathrm{ch}(f_\ast\mathcal{E})\cdot f^\ast(Z))=\mathrm{ch}(f_\ast(\mathcal{E}))\cdot Z$ (The product in the left-hand side is problematic)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Hopefully I haven't made a mistake! This is just the projection formula on $\mathrm{CH}(X)_\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathrm{ch}$ denotes the Chern character. Please let me know if I wrote nonsense!

Comment: But $\mathrm{ch}(f_\ast\mathcal{E})$ lives downstairs and $f^\ast(Z)$ upstairs. How do you multiply them?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Good point. I think I conflated things in transcription from memory of the projection formula, and the $f_\ast$ coming from $f_\ast(\mathcal{E})$. Let me erase that for now, and I'll try and fix it later. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Alex Youcis, may I ask a silly question, the direct image of locally free sheaf in general needs not to be a locally free sheaf correct?

Comment: @yili Hey. Let's prove the claim for a general finitely presented finite flat morphism (e.g. a finite flat morphism of smooth proper geometrically connected curves). Recall that for a finitely presented module, it is flat if and only if it's projective. So, it suffices to show that $f_\ast\mathcal{E}$ is flat and finitely presented. As $f$ is affine we can reduce to the case when $X=\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ and $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. So, we can write $\mathcal{E}=\widetilde{M}$ for some finitely presented flat $B$-module $M$. Recall then that $f_\ast\mathcal{E}$ is just $\widetilde{M}$,

Comment: where we are now viewing $M$ as an $A$-module via the map $A\to B$. In particular, as $A\to B$ is finitely presented and flat, and $M$ is finitely presented and flat, we deduce that $M$ is finitely presented and flat as an $A$-module. Thus, $f_\ast\mathcal{E}$ is a vector bundle.

Comment: Thank you Alex, nice proof, your blog is well written.